# Regex pattern with special characters, digits and letters all combined

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Say I have a regex pattern like this:

```
/^\*HELLO\*/
```

Just looking for the string "`*HELLO*`". But then I completely want to change it up so I do this:

```
/^\*&$&^*2@H\*/
```

Now I'm looking for the string "`*&$&^*2@H*`".

How should I change my regex pattern to check for such a complex string with all those different characters?

Comment: If you just looking for a some literal string, you shouldn't use regexes in the first place. `str.includes("hello")` should do just fine.

Comment: Except he is looking at the beginning of input string. More in need of `startsWith()` @georg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape the special characters in your pattern, wich are used as tokens by Regex, such as `*,^ and $`. Or you will end up with an error claiming about a wrong pattern in your regex.

This is how should be your regex: [`/\*&\$&\^\*2@H\*/`](https://regex101.com/r/oFpH8j/1).

Furthermore if you are searching for the `string` with `.indexOf()` or `.includes()` methods, you can just pass the string as it is.

```
str.indexOf("^\*&$&^*2@H\*");
```